# Short story about a man who plans to live forever and ends up preserved as an exhibit in the future

Tags: story-identification, cryogenics

I once read a story about a man who schemed and plotted his way to wealth and sought immortality by preserving himself to be woken in the future. The story ended with him being a display at a museum in the distant future, a clever twist on his ambitions.
Does anyone know the name of this story?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152708/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: I recall a short story where a person perfected a serum to let him live forever, but was afraid to take it until he had lived out most of his life. When he finally took it he discovered that it stopped him from dying, but not ageing. I thought I recalled him ending up in a museum, as a curiosity. I will try to find the book, possibly a Kuttner collection or shorts.